# SVG path length up to the specific point at path

Tags: javascript, svg

`SVGGeometryElement` has `getTotalLength()` method which returns the full length of the path, but is there any way to calculate length up to the specific point `(x, y)` which belongs to the path?

Comment: a specific x,y may belong to the path multiple times if the path crosses itself. You could call getPointAtLength(in float distance) multiple times increasing the distance and seeing when it gets close to the point you're looking for.

Comment: It can be done for simple paths linme line to (`L`, `H`, `V`), arc (`A`), Quadratic Bezier (`Q`)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky assuming that my path is a straight line or an arc which doesn't cross itself, how can I calculate this "subpath" length? Can you give a basic example please, or you meant the way mentioned by Robert?(calling `getPointAtLength` multiple times)

Comment: Here is a SO snippet (from Enxaneta) you can play with ``getPointAtLength`` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878090/position-an-object-along-a-path-in-svg/58879048#58879048